# Kehuna 'acquired' by 24?

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof, priestly-gifts-matanot-kehunah

In the (abusely so-called) [6th pereq of avot](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6.6?with=Commentary),

> גדולה תורה יותר מן הכהונה ומן המלכות, שהמלכות נקנית ב30 מעלות, והכהונה ב24, והתורה נקנית ב48 דברים. ואלו הן בתלמוד בשמיעת האוזן וכולי

While one must 'acquire' Torah by the 48 things, that are a work to enhance himself; what the meaning of kehuna 'acquired' by 24 things?

1. Kehuna is a state received by birth lineage, and not 'acquired' ?
2. According to the Bartenura ad loc, these 24 things are the 24 gifts listed in Bava Qama 110b; in which sense these gifts make one acquire kehuna?

Comment: I always thought this means that Kohanim have 24 good qualities, and in that merit they get the 24 gifts.  I've never pursued it further than that though.

Comment: @Heshy that makes a nice explanation of Torah by 48 way, not that you need the ways, just these thing happen when one learns Torah

Comment: "abusely"? That's a bit exaggerated. It's incorrect to call it "Avot". However, common parlance has referred to Pirkei Avot as the activity done Shabbat afternoons after Mincha during the spring / summer months (fine - fall / winter months in Australia and c.) It's just a reference to the activity as in "we're learning Pirkei Avot." So, 20 of the 24 weeks it's correct to say "Avot". Being incorrect or ignorant doesn't equate to abuse.

Comment: @danf abuse is a perfectly appropriate term here. It's used like abuse of notation not abuse of spouses.

Answer (score 4):

The [Zero'a Yemin on this Mishna](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.6.6?lang=he&p2=Zeroa_Yamin.6.6.1&lang2=he) asks and answers your question.

There are 24 prerequisites to be a functional Cohen, corresponding to the 24 gifts they were allotted. This is his list - I added the numbers.

> והכהונה בכ״ד מעלות. מצאתי כתוב בס׳ ישן נושן כ״י וז״ל הכהונה נתנת בכ״ד מעלות וכנגדם נתנו כ״ד מתנות ואלו הם.‏
>    1 קדושה.‏
>    2 טהרה.‏
>    3 בגדי שש.‏
>    4 פארי המגבעות לכבוד ולתפארת.‏
>    5 פאר תספורת ראש כל שלשים יום.‏
>    6 לנפש לא יטמא.‏
>    7 לא יקרחו קרחה בראשם.‏
>    8 ופאת זקנם לא יגלחו.‏
>   9  ובבשרם לא ישרטו שרטת.‏
>    10 אשה זונה וחללה ואשה גרושה מאישה לא יקחו.‏
>    11 כל אשר בו מום לא יקרב איש עור.‏
>    12 ולא פסח.‏
>    13 ולא חרום.‏
>    14 ולא שרוע.‏
>    15 ולא שבר יד.‏
>    16 
>   ולא שבר רגל.‏
>    17 ולא גבן.‏
>    18 ולא דק.‏
>    19 ולא תבלול בעינו.‏
>    20 ולא גרב.‏
>    21 ולא ילפת.‏
>    22 ולא מרוח אשך.‏
>    23 ולא בעל מום אחר.‏
>    24 וחייבים לנקות עצמם מכל כיעור עכ״ל‏
>    ולפי שראיתי למפ׳ שפירשו בכ״ד מעלות שהם כ״ד מתנות כהונה לכן העתקתי פירוש הנז׳ דהנאני דא״ש טפי לשון כ״ד מעלות. ומה גם לפי מ״ש הרב כלי יקר שנתנה לכהני׳ עוד מתנת חמשה ועשרים והיא גדולה מהכ״ד והיא ברכ׳ כהני׳ וזו כ״ה תברכו עיין בספרו פ׳ נשא ופ׳ קרח. ולפירוש המפרשים הו״לל כ״ה מעלות לדברי הרב הנז׳ אכן לפי הרב הכותב הנז׳ ניחא:‏

---

Alternately one could use the approach of the [Lechem Shamayim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.6.6?lang=he&p2=Lechem_Shamayim_on_Pirkei_Avot.6.6.1&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he) who notes that by Kehuna the word "acquired" is missing, since it's a Gcd-given gift and not something they need to acquire.

> והכהונה בכ"ד. עשר במקדש. חטאת. וחטאת העוף. אשם. ואשם תלוי. זבחי שלמי צבור. לוג שמן של מצורע. שתי הלחם. לחם הפנים. שירי מנחות. מנחת העומר. וארבע בירושלים. הבכורה (בכור תם) והבכורים. ומורם מן התודה. ומאיל נזיר. ועורות קדשים. ועשר בגבולים. תרומה. ותרומת מעשר. חלה. ראשית הגז. מתנות. פדיון הבן. ופדיון פטר חמור. שדה אחוזה. ושדה חרמים. גזל הגר: **בכהונה לא אמר נקנית**. **כי כל בני אהרן שוין בה**. ואף ע"פ שאין נותנין תרומות ומעשרות אלא לכהן חבר:‏

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, "real" kohanim have an empiric wisdom, that they gathered from various situations.

Particularly, by receiving the 24 gifts, they deal with the world of the fields (teruma), the Levites (terumat maaser), various sinners (qorban chatat and asham), the metzora (oil log), etc

From all these situations, they are aware of several levels of the nation, and could accomplish "they will teach your laws to Jacob and your Torah to Israel..."